# Normalizing random samples with guassian pdf

Tags: matlab

I have a question about normalizing a normal pdf in MATLAB

Assume we have 1000 number of random samples, I draw the pdf using `ksdensity` but the diagram is not normalized.

How do I normalize the pdf (with random samples)?

This is my code:

```
for i=1:1000          
    x(i,1)=normrnd(1100, 0.01*1100);
end

ksdensity(x(i,1))
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code is invalid because you are using i outside the loop

Comment: It is working in my matlab!!!

Comment: @Farbod That's because `i` doesn't evaporate after the loop, but it will be equal to `1000`.  By the way, you don't need to run `normrnd` in a loop, just do `x = normrnd(1100,0.01*1100,[1000,1]);`.  Anyway, **what you want is**: `ksdensity(x)` or maybe `ksdensity(x(:,1))` if x actually has other columns.

Comment: The result _is_ already normalized: its area equals 1. Check it